# shell Script should validate current logged user's password while running script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

After run my script, i am giving my password as input to script.

First script validates if my given password is correct and then script should start remaining process

In my script.

```
echo -n "Enter Password: "
stty -echo
read passwd
stty echo

#Here i want to evaluate $passwd having corresponding user's system password or not

# <Then some process start>
```

Comment: why? is the user already logged in?

Comment: I think you are trying to emulate `sudo` behaviour!

Comment: script shuld get user credential before starting some process.

Comment: As per my requirement script will take too much of time to complete this process. So in middle of processing, i am going to use user's password. So i want to get user's password in starting stage and evaluate password is correct

Comment: Here process means some operation going to take care by script

Comment: while I don't recommend you to do it, you can use `su` and `expect` to check if the password is correct.

Comment: After using 'su' & 'expect' command, we have to call our script manually(unable to continue the process after calling su or expect)